# Manejo de fechas y horas en respuesta JSON

Tags: php, json, timezone

Hola amigos nuevamente recurro a esta fuente de conocimiento ya que tengo un detalle al manejar la representacion de una fecha que me devuelve un JSON ya que la fecha y hora que me devuelve este JSON viene en formato UTC "11-04-22 13:07:53 UTC" y yo necesito convertirlo a horario -06:00 (Mexico), hasta ahora lo que yo habia intentado fue partir ese datos en dos fecha / hora y hacer el manejo a la hora restarle los segundos necesarios a la hora que se me muestra y si lo consegui, pero por alguna razon se me esta afectando la fecha y me estra mostrando la del dia actual, mi pregunta es existe manera de hacerle el tratamiendo de una vez o algo mas fiable? De ante mano gracias anexo mi codigo.

```
<?php                                                                                       
$last_conn = json_encode($device_info['last_connected_at']); // 11-04-22 13:07:53 UTC                                                                                                                                                                   
$date = $device_info['last_connected_at'];
$date = substr($date, 0, -4);   
$salida = new DateTime($date);  
$salida->setTimeZone(new DateTimeZone('-3400'));

$date2 = json_encode($device_info['last_connected_at']);
$date2 = substr($date2, -4, 0); 
$salida2 = new DateTime($date2);    
$salida2->setTimeZone(new DateTimeZone('-0500'));                                          
                                                                                           
echo $salida2 $salida; ?>
```

Comment: No entiendo la asignación en la primera línea. ¿Podrías explicar lo que significa esa línea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes hacerlo con [DateTime](https://www.php.net/manual/es/class.datetime.php)

```
> $dtime = "11-04-22 13:07:53 UTC";
> $dtobj = DateTime::CreateFromFormat('d-m-y H:i:s e', $dtime, new DateTimeZone('UTC'));
> $dtobj->setTimeZone(new DateTimeZone('America/Mexico_City'));
>
> echo $dtobj->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
2022-04-11 08:07:53
>
> echo $dtobj->format('c');
2022-04-11T08:07:53-05:00
```

Usé `Mexico_City`, pero puedes revisar la tabla de [zonas admitidas](https://www.php.net/manual/es/timezones.america.php) y cambiarlo a lo que necesites.

Revisa la [tabla de formatos](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.date.php) para que devuelvas la salida en formato deseado.

Comment: Mcuhas gracias funciono a la perfeccion

Answer (score 0):

La función [`date_create_from_format()`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/datetime.createfromformat.php) analiza una cadena con una fecha formateada:

```
$salida = date_create_from_format( 'T d-m-y G:i:s T'
                                 , 'UTC 11-04-22 13:07:53 UTC' 
                                 );
$salida->setTimeZone( new DateTimeZone('-0600') );
echo $salida->format( DateTimeInterface::W3C ); // 2022-04-11T07:07:53-06:00
```

Comment: Lo intente y no me esta funcionando, puede que lo este implementando mal. O a lo mejor esta mal explicado lo que necesito. `$last_conn` o  `$date` me devuelve el valor de la fecha y hora de ultima conexion, sin embargo esta viene en TZ UTC, lo que necesito es que esa fecha y hora que me devuelve si muestre en un `echo` ya en -06:00